# How can I call a variable from one feature file to another feature file using Karate API Testing

Tags: karate

```
Feature: Add data

Scenario: Add unique data

Given url
And request {name: '#(name)', lastName: '#(lastName)'}
And method POST
Then status 200
And def res = response
And def newId = res.data.id
```

One id will be generated as soon as above api is called. I want to use the id generated in another file to update the data. I have stored the id in 'newId' variable. How can I use this variable and its value in another feature file?

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in detail in [the documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files) - you should *actually* read it :)

So if you have a feature `called.feature` as follows:

```
Feature:

Scenario:
    * print newId
```

You can add this as the last line of the code you posted:

```
* call read('called.feature') { newId: '#(newId)' }
```

Comment: I tried doing the steps you mentioned but it gave me error: 
javascript evaluation failed

Comment: @NehaBagtharia then the only suggestion I have is to follow these instructions, all the best: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: can we pass multiple parameters? also when passing single parameter when I retrieve the value in another feature file it retrieves the value whatever we give in-between ''

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan can't understand. ask a new question, make it simple and clear please

Comment: @PeterThomas I have posted as a question: [karate-how-can-we-retrieve-the-value-from-called-feature-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61587366/karate-how-can-we-retrieve-the-value-from-called-feature-file)