# Passing a variable from one feature file into another as a part of request URL(not query parameter) in Karate

Tags: karate

I have a feature that generates a vehicle id and is stored as a variable in the feature. I want to pass this id as a part of the request URL in another feature as a sort of a teardown activity.

This is how I called it from a feature called activateVehicle.feature

```
Scenario : Activate a vehicle   

    * header X-API-Key = apiKey
    * def result = callonce read('createVehicle.feature')
    * def vehicleId = result.vId

 # some workflow steps
  ........
  ........
  ........

 # tear down - delete the vehicle created
  * call read('deleteVehicle.feature'){ vehcileId: '#(vehicleId)' }
```

In the called feature - deleteVehicle.feature

```
Scenario: Delete a vehicle 
  * header X-API-Key = apiKey
  * def myurl = 'https://xxx/vehicle'+ vehicleId +'?permanent=yes'


    Given myurl
    And request ''
    When method delete
    Then status 200
```

Am I right in the approach? I want to reuse deleteVehicle.feature in other workflows as well and hence not doing this operation in the same activateVehicle.feature(which would have been very easy). I referred to the documentation too but it shows how we can use the variables in in the request body but not as a variable that can be used anywhere in the called feature. I don't want to use it in the request body (but want to use it as a part of the request URL) For example:

```
 Scenario:
 Given url loginUrlBase
 And request { userId: '#(username)', userPass: '#(password)' }
```

I also referred to [How can I call a variable from one feature file to another feature file using Karate API Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382206/how-can-i-call-a-variable-from-one-feature-file-to-another-feature-file-using-ka?rq=1). I followed suit for a solution but am getting a javascript error:

```
 feature.deleteVehicle: -unknown-:11 - javascript evaluation failed: 
 'https://xxx/vehicle'+ vehicleId +'?permanent=yes', ReferenceError: "vehicleId" 
  is not  defined in <eval> at line number 1
  feature.SVT: SVT.feature:80 - javascript evaluation failed: vehicleId: '#(vehicleId)' }, <eval>:1:14 Expected eof 
   but found }
   vehicleId: '#(vehicleId)' }
                             ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 14
```

Can someone kindly help and advise please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you simplify your example ? The only thing I can make out is you need a space after the `call` feature and before the call argument:

```
* call read('deleteVehicle.feature') { vehcileId: '#(vehicleId)' }
```

The pattern we generally recommend is to setUp not tearDown as tearDown has a risk of not executing if you had an error.  That said, please see hooks: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks

Sometimes you should just keep it simple and call a feature (with args) only where you need it.

Comment: That was the issue. The space between the call feature and the arguement. That solved the issue. Thanks @Peter. Will have a look at hooks too. I am hoping to wrote an after Feature scenario that handles the tearDown as you rightly pointed out, failures above the tearDown will not execute it. Thanks once again Peter

Comment: The other mistake I made was: ```Given myurl``` should be ```Given url myurl```