# Karate: How can we retrieve the value from called feature file

Tags: karate

I have two parameter in feature file A and I pass those values to another feature file called B.

But I am unable to retrieve the values as expected in Feature file B

*CODE:*

**Feature File A:**

```
And def Response = response
And def token = response.metaData.paging.token
And def totalPages = response.metaData.paging.totalPages

* def xyz = 
"""
  function(times){
    for(currentPage=1;currentPage<=times;currentPage++){
      karate.log('Run test round: '+(currentPage));
      karate.call('ABC.feature', {getToken:token, page:currentPage});

    }
    java.lang.Thread.sleep(1*1000);
  }
"""
* call xyz totalPages
```

**Feature File B:**

```
* def token = '#(getToken)'
* def currentPage = '#(page)'
```

But the output was

#getToken

#page

What would be the best way? to these values for further utilization.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
* def token = getToken
* def currentPage = page
```

Here's another thing, any variable defined in the calling feature will be visible, e.g. `token` so most of the time you don't need to pass arguments:

```
* print token
* print totalPages
```

Please avoid JS for loops as far as possible: https://github.com/intuit/karate#loops - and actually you seem to have missed the data-driven testing approach that Karate recommends: https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-karate-way

If you are still stuck, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I tried and it gives the following exception:
*com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: -unknown-:7 - javascript evaluation failed: getToken, ReferenceError: "getToken" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1*

Comment: As you said, I could use the token due to its visibility and could not access the page

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan I have nothing more to add. wait for someone else to help or follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: On the called feature file, I could print the page value but I cannot assign to the parameter.

Example: 
**And print pageNo** --- *prints the value*
**And And param pageNumber** = *pageNo*
**And print pageNumber** --- *prints empty*

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue